# The {file} may have been changed by another user since you last saved it. In that case what do you want to do?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, microsoft-teams, collaboration

This is regarding editing a shared Excel file on a Windows 10 computer.

**Context:**
The excel file is sitting in a Microsoft Teams site (ie. SharePoint) and being opened in the desktop version of Excel.

To clarify, the Teams file location is mounted onto the Windows File explorer via the sync button on Teams:

[image]

**I keep getting this error:**

[image]

But I've not found how to avoid it.

Any ideas? I am not looking to make a copy of the file because that breaks the links I've shared to the active file. But also I don't know what changes I'd be overwriting if I choose "Overwrite changes"

Comment: This likely has something to do with the way Excel opens files. MS documents indicate that on updating an existing Excel file, in order to provide resilience against network interruptions or similar causes of file writing failure, a temporary file is created in the save folder, and when the data is fully written the original Excel file is deleted and the temporary file is renamed to match the original.

https://serverfault.com/a/34161/284398